# Fail Safe Iterator

Tags: java, iterator, concurrenthashmap

What i know about fail safe Iterator is that it creates a copy of original data structure and iterates over it to allow concurrent modifcations. 
I have some confusions like:

1. How are modifications reflected back into original data structure?
2. If  we have two threads:
    Thread A: Iterator one removes an element(Element A)
    Thread B: Iterator two has started iterating. How it will be communicated to  this iterator that the original DS has got changed.

Comment: Who says it will be? What data structure are you talking about anyway?

Comment: And where have you read that a copy of the original structure is being done? It's not. Read the javadoc of the iterator() method of the collection you're using: it should tell how the iterator behaves.

Comment: Can you tell how internally the fail safe or weakly consistent iterators work from documentation. The iterators allow concurrent modification

Answer (score 1):

As you already know the "fail-safe" iterator works on a clone copy of original collection. Explanation:

1. How are modifications reflected back into original data structure?

   If you modify the collection while iterating over it then the changes happen to the original copy and not the cloned copy(which you are using for iteration). So, the structure of current cloned copy is intact.  See below:

   ```
   public class FailSafeIteratorExample {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
           // Creating a ConcurrentHashMap

       ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();
       // Adding elements to map
       map.put("abc", 1);

       // Here, we are working on clone copy.
       Iterator<String> it = map.keySet().iterator();
       while (it.hasNext()) {
           String key = (String) it.next();
           System.out.println(key + " : " + map.get(key));
           map.put("mno", 2); // This will not be reflected in the Iterator
       }
       System.out.println("\n\n");

       // Another clone copy just created with latest changes.
       // This will print the existing element with newly added element("mno")
       it = map.keySet().iterator();
       while (it.hasNext()) {
           String key = (String) it.next();
           System.out.println(key + " : " + map.get(key));

       }
   }}
   ```

while iterating over collection for first time, we inserted a new entry "mno" which doesn't reflects in cloned copy. But when we iterate it for second time, then the another cloned copy is created from original collection which has this newly added entry "mno" hence, it is printed.

2. Threads: 
   There is no way of communication happens when individual thread modifies the collection as they work on cloned copies. They are not be aware of changes made by other threads to the original copy.

Hope this helps!

Comment: @ ProgrammerBoy   Yes man.  I know this that change happens on original copy. I wanted to know how iterator internally communicates it .

Comment: Iterators here are just for traversing, what i got. They dont perform any mutation.

Answer (score 0):

Fail Safe Iterator :

Fail Safe Iterator makes copy of the internal data structure (object array) and iterates over the copied data structure.Any structural modification done to the iterator affects the copied data structure.  So , original data structure remains  structurally unchanged .Hence , no ConcurrentModificationException throws by the fail safe iterator.

Two  issues associated with Fail Safe Iterator are :

1. Overhead of maintaining the copied data structure i.e memory.
2. Fail safe iterator does not guarantee that the data being read is the data currently in the original data structure.

According to Oracle docs , fail safe iterator is ordinarily too costly, but may be more efficient than alternatives when traversal operations vastly outnumber mutations, and is useful when you cannot or don’t want to synchronize traversals, yet need to preclude interference among concurrent threads. The "snapshot" style iterator method uses a reference to the state of the array at the point that the iterator was created. This array never changes during the lifetime of the iterator, so interference is impossible and the iterator is guaranteed not to throw ConcurrentModificationException.The iterator will not reflect additions, removals, or changes to the list since the iterator was created. Element-changing operations on iterators themselves (remove(), set(), and add()) are not supported. These methods throw UnsupportedOperationException.

Comment: the first answer says it reflects the original copy and here you say it does not. I dont know which one is true.

Answer (score -1):

1. You can not modificate the collection over which you are iterating (concurent modification). If you modify the objects in the collection they are modified in original collection as well.
2. it will not be communicated. You are iterating over a copy. And if you try to modify the collection see 1.

Comment: .Yeah exactly.. I also got the same answer while I was searching. I dont know then why they provide those methods which are not supported . Is it because they want to reuse the same interface again and again to show reusability and maintain the same prototype of methods.